# Is there a way to get the list of JavaScript files that are getting loaded on the page?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I want to load the JavaScript files using `document.createElement()`, since that is better for the page load. Is there a way, maybe in a preprocess hook, to get the list of JavaScript files that are getting loaded on the page?

Comment: You can get a list of files from hook_js_alter (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/8.5.x)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can get them from that hook, but how do I get them back in the html.html.twig? Because then I can write a new way to load them through document.createElement.

Comment: @Jaypan is correct. Since you are going to add the JavaScript files to the page, you also need to avoid Drupal adds them. `hook_js_alter()` allows to get the list of JavaScript files, and at the same time avoid Drupal adds them to the page.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to add the list of javascripts to the html.html.twig?

Comment: The question is why you need to get them to html.html.twig. If you want to use them in JavaScript, you wouldn't need them in this template at all.

Comment: @Jaypan if JS code has to be in <body> instead of <head>, where is the place to add the JS code to load/manipulate array of JS files returned by `hook_js_alter()` ?

Comment: @Jaypan The way Drupal is loading javascripts at the moment is adding <script src="yourscript.js"></script> to the page. For pagespeed / loading purposes I want to load them through document.createElement function. If you have another suggestion to do this rather than getting the javascripts in an array and writing this function in html.html.twig I love to hear it.

Answer (score -1):

Hi By using drupal_get_js.You can get the list of Javasript files in drupal7.

function mytheme_preprocess_page (&$vars, $hook) {
  if (true) {
    drupal_add_js (drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(); // necessary in D7?
  }
}

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Drupal 8.